# Track multiple github public repos for commits

Tags: github, tracking

Hi dos any one got an idea for a software or something that makes it possible to check different repos for new commits ?

Got quite a few repos thats not mine i want to track if there is any new commits, but cant find a good way.

So i am hoping someone got an idea

Answer (score 0):

1. Use RSS feeds (like https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commits/master.atom) and any RSS reader. You can use some "rss to email" service (like [Blogtrottr](https://blogtrottr.com/)) to get email notifications about new commits.
2. Use `github-notifier` script from [`git-notifier`](https://github.com/rsmmr/git-notifier) package. You will need some hosting with git + cron + python support to make it work.

I'm using both depending on scenario. Feeds are simpler to make it work, but you will get less info, and you can miss some commits, since commits history is not really linear and only last 20 commits are visible in feed by default.